# PLSQL: random timestamp between 2 timestamps

Tags: oracle, random, plsql, timestamp

I have a timestamp which represents the current timestamp:

```
now := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
tomorrow := now + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

Now I want to render a random timestamp between those 2 values,
I tried with DBMS_RANDOM but it doesn't work

Any Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will generate a random timestamp between the current timestamp and sysdate+1:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + 
       dbms_random.value(0, TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - 
       TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+1) 
FROM dual;
```

As PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
  l_ran_time TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
  SELECT SYSDATE + 
         dbms_random.value(0, SYSDATE - 
         SYSDATE+1) 
  INTO l_ran_time
  FROM dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(l_ran_time);
END;
/
```

Comment: I don't see why not. I've updated the answer with an anonymous block.

Comment: If you like the result please mark the question as answered.

Comment: You are correct. I had that script lying around that was a bit different so just used that one. I've edited to remove the typecasting.