# Find a random timestamp between 2 timestamps using PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I am not familiar with PL/SQL.

I am looking for a function/code that would give me a random timestamp that is between 2 other timestamps.  For example If I would like to find a random timestamp between

```
12-FEB-18 12.00.00.000000 AM - 13-MAR-19 12.00.00.000000 AM
```

I see the following post.

[PLSQL: random timestamp between 2 timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608010/plsql-random-timestamp-between-2-timestamps)

But that seems to give me a timestamp between current timestamp and another timestamp.  Is there a way to generate a timestamp that falls between 2 timestamps?

Comment: Just substitute your other timestamp column for current_timestamp. There is nothing special about current_timestamp except *predefined* value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided gives you the answer. All you really need to do is replace the SYSDATE, which gives you the current date, with your current time.

The following code will give you a random date from a from-to range of the dates entered:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(date_1, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + 
       dbms_random.value(0, TO_DATE(date_2, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - 
       TO_DATE(date_1, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) 
FROM dual;
```